# Is there a way to access the nth JSON element with Python?

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON for example:

```
"products": {
    "5117293": {
        "id": 5117293,
        "brandId": 12,
        "price": "12$"
        "mediaById": {
            "104290597": {
                "id": "17_104290597",
                "group": "swatch",
                "type": "image",
                "src": "https://foo.com/image1.jpg"
              },
            "104725944": {
                "id": "7_104725947",
                "group": "main",
                "type": "image",
                "src": "https://foo.com/image2.jpg"
            }
        },
}
```

Let's say I want to access the second image **image2.jpg**. How do I do that with Python JSON library without knowing the ID? (accessing the second element in this example). Here's what I tried and obviously failed (EDIT: I realize it won't work, I just want a similar way).

```
image = json_content['products']["5117293"]["mediaById"][1]["src"]
```

This would print a key error.

Comment: Depending on your version of Python `dict` might be unordered, so "the second" element doesn't really have a meaning.

Comment: `mediaById` is not an array, it's an object/dictionary. You probably should not depend on the order always being the same.

Comment: I realize that the code above would not work because JSON is not a list and is unordered. I just want a similar way to access the nth element depending on the order assuming it won't change.

Comment: You need to loop as key-value pairs inside `json_content['products']["5117293"]["mediaById"]` and check if the value corresponding to the `src` field contains the string `image2`. Indexing does not work for dicts in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import json

j = """
{
    "products": {
        "5117293": {
            "id": 5117293,
            "brandId": 12,
            "price": "12$",
            "mediaById": {
                "104290597": {
                    "id": "17_104290597",
                    "group": "swatch",
                    "type": "image",
                    "src": "https://foo.com/image1.jpg"
                },
                "104725944": {
                    "id": "7_104725947",
                    "group": "main",
                    "type": "image",
                    "src": "https://foo.com/image2.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

d = json.loads(j)
print(list(d['products']['5117293']['mediaById'].items())[1][1]['src']) #for the second item
>>> https://foo.com/image2.jpg
#print(list(d['products']['5117293']['mediaById'].items())[0][1]['src']) #for the first item
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the "second" index based on however the ordering falls, you can use:

```
nth = 2
nth_image_id = json_content['products']["5117293"]["mediaById"].keys()[nth - 1]
image = json_content['products']["5117293"]["mediaById"][nth_image_id]["src"]
```

As others have pointed out in the comments, the order may not be well defined. However in this case, if you know that the ID number will always be increasing, you might be able to use that to get the nth element, in another sense of "nth" that is well defined.

```
nth = 2
# determine the nth id
image_ids = json_content['products']["5117293"]["mediaById"].keys()
image_ids = [int(x) for x in image_ids]
image_ids.sort()
nth_image_id = image_ids[nth - 1]
# pull the nth image
image = json_content['products']["5117293"]["mediaById"][nth_image_id]["src"]
```

Comment: Well, this will definitely work if the ID is increasing, but that's not the case here. However, your answer makes total sense in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by using a temporary list to get the media IDs and accessing the second element of that list.

```
images = json_content['products']["5117293"]['mediaById']
imagesList = []
for imageID in images:
    imagesList.append(imageID)
image = prod['mediaById'][imagesList[1]]['src']
```